# Wicket custom namespace

Tags: java, namespaces, wicket

I have custom namespace for wicket. I try to get the "href" of a link. However, it gives null pointer exception. Below is the code:

```
<html xmlns:foobar>
```

It appears that org.apache.wicket.markup.parser.filter.WicketNamespaceHandler is responsible to extract the namespace from  and set it for the MarkupResourceStream.

```
<a foobar:id="fredLink" href="abc.html" >fred</a>
```

Jave code:

```
tester.getTagByWicketId("fredLink").getAttribute("href");
```

It returns null pointer exception. If I change the namespace back to normal namespace (i.e., wicket) then it does not produce any error and returns the href.

Any help?

Comment: `<html xmlns:foobar>` is not valid XML.

Comment: I am sorry, I did not get it. If I just replace foobar with wicket then it works all fine. I think, XML is correct and according to wicket standards.

Comment: It could be a bug in WicketTester/TagTester. Please create a test case and attach it to a ticket in JIRA.

Comment: I already looked at their bug-reporting system. They do not have this issue. It was fixed in version 1.5.x. There are some other examples online (even in their bug-reporting website) that use non-standard namespace. I am sure it supports and it's not a bug.